# Internet Explorer 6 pin to system tray

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, plugins

I run citrix web interface on an IE tab. So always one window is kept opened. Is it possible to pin that IE window to system tray?

I don't want it to be part of program list on Taskbar.

additional info:

OS: Windows XP,

Browser version: IE6

Answer (score 1):

If you install [IE7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2) you have browser tabs which can hide citrix window in between.

Comment: thanks. But I don't use IE for anything else .. :) so multiple tabs aren't really worth ;)

Comment: http://www.teamcti.com/trayit/trayit.htm
Windows 7 solves the problem fro goot - it has taskbar like a MAC with shortcut icons serving as program icons.

Comment: trayit is for XP

Comment: oh .. you mean theme? thats good suggestion :)

Comment: upvoted .. +1, waiting for some more suggestions .....

Comment: trayit software which i sort of proposed.... click related: in google for more....

Comment: sure .. I will try it and comeback to you in case of success :) ..